# Chat history of tensor flow chat bot in XML

Tags: python, xml

How to store the chat history as xml data using python ?

Chat bot is built using tensorflow,tflearn.

Please do help me on this.

Comment: Please provide more details. What have you tried and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Hi you can try looking at [xml.etree](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html)  outstanding library for xml. If you need any specific details on how to create/read/write the docs have everything, or just reach out.